# Delphi XE7 UP1 Android 5.0 & 5.1 Hot Fix Doesn't Work

Tags: android, delphi, delphi-xe7

I'm using Delphi XE7 UP1 on Windows 10 Pro X64 TR, fix to XE7's Android 5.x problem i've applied Embarcadero's "lollipop_update_010715" and lollipop_update_011415 but i'm still having trouble the run android application on my phone. My phone is HTC ONE M9 Android 5.1 & Using ViperOneM9 3.5.0 ROM. I'm creating a blank form in Delphi and trying to run for Android, it's rendering application and sending to my phone without error, when application started splash screen shows up and application closing immediately.I've searched on forums and everybody says it happens if you have image on your form but in my case there are no images or buttons, i'm just using a blank form, also i've tried to remove splash screen's images but result was the same. I've managed the capture the error messages with Catlog as below, but frankly speaking i didn't understand what's wrong,peoples are saying those hot fixes should solve the problem, i'm wondering what am i missing ?

Catlog Output :

```
10-07 08:36:49.190 E/SQLiteLog(22891): (284) automatic index on parts(_filepath)
10-07 08:37:31.870 E/BackupManagerService(1182): No restore metadata available, so not restoring
10-07 08:37:31.870 E/BackupManagerService(1182): Unexpected restore callback into state FINAL
10-07 08:37:31.920 E/PackageActionReceiver(30638): ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED
10-07 08:37:31.950 E/BackupManagerService(1182): Duplicate finish
10-07 08:37:31.990 E/ExternalAccountType(30638): Unsupported attribute readOnly
10-07 08:37:32.950 E/ActivityThread(22243): Performing stop of activity that is not resumed: {com.nolanlawson.logcat/com.nolanlawson.logcat.LogcatActivity}
10-07 08:37:32.950 E/ActivityThread(22243): java.lang.RuntimeException: Performing stop of activity that is not resumed: {com.nolanlawson.logcat/com.nolanlawson.logcat.LogcatActivity}
10-07 08:37:32.950 E/ActivityThread(22243):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performStopActivityInner(ActivityThread.java)
10-07 08:37:32.950 E/ActivityThread(22243):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopActivity(ActivityThread.java)
10-07 08:37:32.950 E/ActivityThread(22243):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java)
10-07 08:37:32.950 E/ActivityThread(22243):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java)
10-07 08:37:32.950 E/ActivityThread(22243):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java)
10-07 08:37:32.950 E/ActivityThread(22243):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java)
10-07 08:37:32.950 E/ActivityThread(22243):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java)
10-07 08:37:32.950 E/ActivityThread(22243):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
10-07 08:37:32.950 E/ActivityThread(22243):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
10-07 08:37:32.950 E/ActivityThread(22243):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java)
10-07 08:37:32.950 E/ActivityThread(22243):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java)
10-07 08:37:33.010 E/SQLiteLog(23269): (284) automatic index on clids(identity)
10-07 08:37:33.010 E/SQLiteLog(23269): (284) automatic index on clids(identity)
10-07 08:37:33.210 E/ActivityThread(23269): Failed to find provider info for com.embarcadero.Project1.YPLContentProvider
10-07 08:37:33.340 E/ObjectHelper(23336): Can't find method:setCompatibilityInfo
10-07 08:37:33.440 E/JavaBinder(1182): !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!
10-07 08:37:33.440 E/lowmemorykiller(497): Error writing /proc/23293/oom_score_adj; errno=22
10-07 08:37:34.050 E/InputEventReceiver(1182): Looper::removeFd(328) is failed, result(0), input channel 'e401276 Starting com.embarcadero.Project1 (c)'
10-07 08:37:34.490 E/Prism.WidgetManager(3909): Widget ComponentInfo{com.devhd.feedly/com.devhd.feedly.widget.FeedlyWidgetProvider_4_1} has invalid dimensions (0, 0)
10-07 08:37:34.710 E/Prism.WidgetManager(3909): The same lists. No need to update. skip it.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Venom ROM cause that problem, just flash the HD rom or original stock rom.